# How to make the map returned by GroupBy mutable?

Tags: scala

I have a class that contains a map. I have a lazy val that essentially contains the map grouped by in a particular format. I would want to use it multiple times through a method and then at some point of time clear this map. How do I go about doing something like this.

Example

```
class A(input: Map[key,value]) {
   private lazy val mapgrouped = input.groupBy(_._1.a)
   def useMap()
   {
       //use the mapgrouped Map multiple times
   }

   def clearMap()
   {
      // clear the mapgrouped field here
   }
}
```

Comment: The title of your question is at odds with the body. You ask how to make something immutable in the title, and then ask how to change its value in the body. Please fix one or the other so we can know what is it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have particular performance requirements, I'd advise choosing var-of-immutable rather than val-of-mutable.  The former allows for safe publication: readers don't necessarily get the most recent version of the data, but they're guaranteed to get an internally consistent snapshot that other threads can't tamper with.

In your case I'd probably do something like this:

```
private var mMapGrouped: Option[Map[A,B]] = None

def useMap() {
  val map = mMapGrouped.getOrElse {
    val newMap = rebuildTheMap(...)
    mMapGrouped = Some(newMap)
    newMap
  }

  doStuffWith(map)
}

def clearMap() {
  mMapGrouped = None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the evaluation strategy of `lazy val` and they are strictly one-shot evaluation of the RHS.

Your grouped map is private, so I assume you don't allow that Map instance itself to leak out. In that case, you can make the `Map` mutable and reset / regenerate its contents on whatever policy you require.

Comment: groupby returns an immutable map. You are suggesting that I convert that to a mutable map?

Comment: Sriram: Sorry, that was careless of me. But yes, I think that's one approach. The other is to use a `var` (there no such thing as a `lazy var`) and generate the initial grouping eagerly and re-generate it, overwriting the grouped map (its var) when you do,

Comment: If I make it a var then I could probably do mapgrouped = None in clearMap() ?

Comment: @SriramSubramanian: Yes, you can use `Option[Map[This, That]]` in the static type for the var. If you let the compiler infer the type from the initial value `None`, then you'll never be able to store a `Some(...)` in it!